# Is it possible to combine two ssh connections into one using PuTTY client for Windows?

Tags: ssh, putty, openssh

Right now, I execute these two commands to ultimately get to the server I want access to using putty's interface

Type in me@intermediate in the hostname field

And once I'm in, I execute - ssh me@destination in the terminal

How can I combine these 2 into a single command that I can type in at Putty's interface?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestions. I was able to solve the issue by following the steps.